# > 20 GB traffic to image on site from AndroidDownloadManager - What is this?

Tags: android, apache, logging

Today I was perusing my munin graphs and logfiles on one of my VPSes running Apache, and I noticed that there was a huge amount of traffic for about a day and a half (averaging 1.2 MB/second of en0 throughput... not too nice for my monthly quotas), all from the same IP address, and all were for one of two files:

```
76.186.15.152 - - [21/Dec/2011:09:41:12 -0600] "GET /sites/lifeisaprayer.com/files/blog-images/squirrel-relax.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 250872 "-" "AndroidDownloadManager"
76.186.15.152 - - [21/Dec/2011:09:43:36 -0600] "GET /sites/lifeisaprayer.com/files/blog-images/crucifix-power-strip-20100831-120018.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 93618 "-" "AndroidDownloadManager"
```

If a request comes from the Android browser, the user agent is something different (don't remember exactly what it is, but it's something like WebKit...).

[image: Apache accesses - by week]

My question is: what does AndroidDownloadManager represent, and what (wild speculation welcome) do you think could've spent that day and a half downloading the exact same image files about a million times, up to 20 times/second?

And why would all these requests be coming from the same IP address... I can't imagine someone had an android tablet or phone sitting around downloading 20ish GB of data. The battery would've died in about 30 minutes—shorter if it was on 4G LTE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't imagine someone had an android tablet or phone sitting around
>   downloading 20ish GB of data. The battery would've died in about 30
>   minutes—especially if it was on 4G LTE!

Any agent (the device making the connection) can present any [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string that it wants to your server. It doesn't mean that a mobile device made all or any of the requests; it just means that "AndroidDownloadManager" was in the `User-Agent` HTTP header.

> And why would all these requests be coming from the same IP address

Denial of service attack? High value datacenters get bombarded with massive amounts of DOS and DDOS traffic. You may or may not be a "high value target", but sending millions of requests with a spoofed user agent string takes only minimal programming knowledge.

And if the attacker is malicious, they might identify a resource that is expensive to serve and target that to cause maximum damage.

Add a firewall rule (or talk to your host) to throttle or block traffic from that IP if it continues to be a problem. Keep in mind you might block wanted traffic as well depending on a variety of factors. It's also possible that the IP is spoofed.

For what it's worth, that IP looks to be from Texas, US:

http://ip-address-lookup-v4.com/ip/76.186.15.152

Comment: I don't think I'm high-value enough to be worth DDOS ;-)

I guess someone could spoof user-agents, but why would they choose AndroidDownloadManager? All I could find on that is a bunch of forum posts asking about implementing it in an Android app...

Comment: Interestingly, a friend of mine lives just a bit south of that pin in Texas... hrm...

Comment: Just block his IP and report him to his ISP.

Comment: @geerlingguy - you might not be high value, but 1) it's so easy to do and 2) you might be part of a high value IP block, for example, big data centers hosting small websites.

Answer (score 1):

AndroidDownloadManager is an API apps can use to download files (it's used by Market I believe for instance.) This likely means you have an app installed responsible for this.

Comment: Since the traffic died off, do you think it could be some social sharing app that somehow featured both of those images for a day or something? (It'd be nice if I would've gotten warning my images would be hotlinked, if that's the case. Silly freeloaders).

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this behavior a few days ago. I had over 1500 requests for each of 4 50MB files over a 14.5 hour period. User agent was AndroidDownloadManager, they all came from a single IP address (OptusNet in Australia), and it appears that the entire file was downloaded each time (at least, my ISP thinks it sent the entire file). I like Joakim's theory.

I can't tell whether the IP address (58.111.194.x) is allocated to a phone or to a cable or DSL modem, because OptusNet provides all of those kinds of service. If it's a phone, maybe it stopped because the account ran out of money. Anyway, it looks like it's a rare thing, and I'll hope it doesn't happen again.

We just tested an app named Android Download Manager on a friends tablet, and the UserAgent string it is sending is "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; NookColor Build/JZO54K)". I'm guessing it might not be the same thing.